# Facebook Android API and Twitter Webview Login integration

Tags: android, twitter, android-fragments, facebook-android-sdk

I have an android app that will require the user to login using either facebook or twitter. I managed to implement both of it and was partly successful. The facebook login was implemented using [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate) tutorial from facebook.

As for the the twitter login, I just used a button that starts the TwitterLoginActivity that carries out the webview login and if it is successful launches the TwitterHomeActivity which is implemented quite similarly to the facebook login in terms of the fragmentation.

So here's the breakdown of the whole Login Impementation

**FacebookHomeActivity** has 3 fragments

- *FacebookSplashFragment*(Option to login with fb or twitter)
- *FacebookSelectionFragment*(shows app menu)
- *FacebookUserSettingsFragmen*(logout user).

**TwitterHomeActivity** has 2 fragments

- *TwitterSelectionFragment* (shows app menu)
- *TwitterUserSettingsFragment* (logout user)

**TwitterLoginActivity** (contains a webview to carry out the authentication through my server which will redirect to the twitter page for login)

The issue, if you haven't seen it yet is that, if i logout from a twitter account, I have to start the FacebookHomeActivity just to see the options to log into facebook or twitter.

Doing this is very hacky and just bad. So I thought if i made it all fragments, it might solve my issue.

**LoginActivity** (host for all things login) contains:

- *LoginSelectionFragment* (choose to login with facebook or twitter)
- *TwitterLoginFragment* (Login user through webview)
- *FacebookSelectionFragment* (authorize user and show menu)
- *TwitterSelectionFragment* (show menu)
- *FacebookUserSettingFragment* (logout fb user)
- *TwitterUserSettingFragment* (logout twitter user)

By making use of this for it to show the correct fragments at different login states:

```
        @Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        // if the session is already open,
        // try to show the selection fragment
        getSupportActionBar().show();
        showFragment(FACEBOOKSELECTION, false);
    }

    else if (Globals.loggedIn() && Globals.isTwitterUser()) {
        // otherwise present the splash screen
        // and ask the person to login.
        getSupportActionBar().show();
        showFragment(TWITTERSELECTION, false);

    } 
    else {
        // otherwise present the splash screen
        // and ask the person to login.
        Globals.logout();
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        showFragment(LOGINSELECTION, false);
    }

}
```

Making all the login logic exist as fragments seems to make sense to me but it does not behave the way i envisioned it to work. Instead it basically runs everything there is in the onStart() in each fragment, so imagine lots of progressDiaglogs popping up and nothing really happens besides that. The backstack is also messed up causing a fragment that was never shown to be shown. Either i'm implementing this wrong or this is a completely wrong way to approach this problem.

My question is: What would be a better way to implement both Facebook Login and Twitter Login if this is not a good way to address the issue.

If the above does make sense and has nothing wrong with it, what do you supposed I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After about 5 days of trying out new methods like isolating the facebook login authentication to its own Activity with its own set of fragments which also failed to behave the way it should, I read up on the [Fragments Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) which gave me a better understanding on how fragments actually work and are meant to work. For anyone facing a similar issue as me, I highly recommend you read up the documentation first.

The FragmentManager or rather the SupportFragmentManager which I use, together with the method beginTransaction(), exposes the method called [replace()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) which will allow you to replace the fragment in the current view with the one you want to display. Here's how i use it:

```
  public void replaceFragment(Fragment f, Boolean addToBackStack) {
        if (addToBackStack) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(android.R.id.content, f).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        } else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(android.R.id.content, f).commit();
        }
    }
```

> The addToBackStack parameter is for you to decide if the user can
>   navigate back to that fragment after you show the new one.

So instead of using the showFragment() that is shown in the Facebook Android API examples, I replaced all of the showFragment() methods with replaceFragment().

The differece between the 2 is that, when you use the showFragment() method whereby you pre-load all the fragments in your Host Activity (In my case LoginActivity.java) what happens is that ALL the fragment's onCreate(), onStart() and onResume() functions are called. This behaviour was bad as some of my fragments started carrying out the code in the onStart() methods causing all the progressDialogs to show as well when they shouldn't.

By using the replaceFragment() method shown above, I can instantiate the fragment only when I need to show it, allowing me to utilize the lifecycle methods (onCreate(), onStart(), onResume() etc) normally.

After the user has logged in successfully, I simply show the user my menu and clear the back stack with the following method:

```
public void clearBackStack() {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    // Get the number of entries in the back stack
    int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
    // Clear the back stack
    for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
        manager.popBackStack();
    }
}
```

> Key areas to clear the back stack would be after the user has
>   successfully logged in, and when the user has successfully logged out.

With this, I am able to control the fragments better, since they behave like activities in terms of its lifecycle.

Hopefully this would be of some help to someone out there.